# jQuery: Get string from attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I am trying to get a string from an attribute like so...

```
$("*").filter(function() {
  $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attrib){
    if (attrib.value == urlHash) {
      console.log(attrib);
      anchorLink = String(attrib);
      console.log(anchorLink);
    }
  });
});
```

`console.log(attrib);` gives me something like `name="top"`, which is exactly what I need except that it is not a string. `console.log(anchorLink)` gives me `[object Attr]`. How can I define `anchorLink` so that it can be used as a string?

Comment: Have you tried the `.toString()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `console.log(attrib);` gives me something like `name="top"`, which is
>   exactly what I need

If string `name="top"` is expected result, you can concatenate attribute `.name` and `.value` properties, placing `=` character on either side of `.value` property

```
anchorLink = `${attrib.name}="${attrib.value}"`;
```

```
anchorLink = attrib.name + '="' + attrib.value + '"';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use: JSON.stringify(attrib);